# How to access popover element with repeated name inside the component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am trying to trigger the toggle function of a popover inside an Angular Material Table.

If a cell in the table has tabbed focus, i would like the popover to open when the user hits the 'Enter' key. This would mimic the behaviour of when the user click's on the table cell.

My problem is that the popover component is given the name #valuePopover which is the same name for all cells in the table.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="value">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let entry;" tabindex="0"
    [satPopoverAnchorFor]="valuePopover" (click)="valuePopover.toggle()" 
    (keypress)="openPopover($event)">
    <span>{{entry.value}}</span>
    <sat-popover #valuePopover hasBackdrop xAlign="start" yAlign="start" (closed)="updateField(entry, $event)">Hello!
    </sat-popover>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

For the (click) event it works fine as it can just call the 'valuePopover.toggle()' function. However, with the keypress event I need to check if it is the enter key that has been pressed, and I need to do this in the component.

```
@ViewChild('valuePopover') popover; 

openPopover(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) popover.toggle();
}
```

The openPopover function always opens the popover of the first cell popover but not the one with the tabbed focus on it!

Does anybody know how I can implement this either in the html or the component?

I am using the 'sat-popover' component which you can find here: https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover

Comment: Log out `event` to the console. You should see `currentTarget`. From here you can determine the DOM element parent and trigger a click event on it, and allow your click handler to do the rest.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane When I output the event.currentTarget I get this: 
    event = {"__zone_symbol__clickfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"scheduled","source":"HTMLTableCellElement.addEventListener:click","zone":"angular","runCount":0}],"__zone_symbol__keypressfalse":[{"type":"eventTask","state":"running","source":"HTMLTableCellElement.addEventListener:keypress","zone":"angular","runCount":2}]}  I don't see how I can get the element parent from this?

Comment: `this.element = event.target` See: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the help of the user Diodeus - James McFarlane, by preventing the default event, and calling the click method of the event.target like so:

```
openPopover(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element:HTMLElement = event.target;
    element.click();
  }
}
```